# Does Python's object class come with an id-based equality method built in?

Tags: python

Does Python's `object` class indeed come with an id-based equality method built in?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i


def test_keyset():
    i1 = A(1)
    i2 = A(1)
    
    # fails:
    assert i1 == i2
```

Comment: The docs of [\_\_eq\_\_](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) say that the default implementation returns True if self is other, which is identity based equality.

Comment: Btw, *dataclasses* have default \_\_eq\_\_ which compares the type and all the fields.